# Can't connect interactions in interaction overview diagram in EA

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, interaction

I have a problem with the Interaction overview diagram in EA.
I cannot connect any control nodes to InteractionUse element I added to the diagram. Or even between two InteractionUse elements.

I'm getting the following error:
*The requested connection is not UML compliant.*

Can anybody give me some advice on this?

Here are some images to demonstrate the problem:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to have been solved in version 16 (tested on build 16.0.1605)

In version 15.2.1560 the problem still occurred.

If upgrading is not an option, you can still disable the strict connector syntax (even if only temporarily) through the settings:

[image]

According to the UML specification (2.5.1) this is indeed a valid connection since in **§ 17.10.1.1 Graphic Nodes** it says:

> Inline Interaction diagrams and InteractionUses are considered special forms of CallBehaviorAction.

Comment: Well, that's the way to let hell break free. This option is just one of the many awful ideas some Sparxian came up with. "We are UML compliant" shouts the salesman. "And we don't care a bit" whispers the developer.

Comment: @qwerty_so what's the alternative? Stop modelling interaction overview diagrams? If you can't upgrade this is the only way forward if you still want to model interaction overview diagrams

Comment: Make software that sticks to specifications instead of letting the bugs run free?

Comment: I would guess that the Sparxian overlooked that note in 17.10.1.1 and made the same assumption as me in my former answer. One of the few case I would not blame Sparx. Now rather the OMG guys since that info is not visible in the printed metamodel (I have not verified that in the XMI).

Comment: @qwerty_so and Geert Bellekens, thanks! I cannot upgrade right now, but I will use your suggestion.